# Static and Dynamic Interface Declarations, Constructor Functions

Tags: typescript

I am a little confused about type definitions:

I want a correct Type Definition for this:

```
   var AClass = function (param) {
        this.field = param;
    };


    var aVariable = new AClass(1);
```

I created this, but the compiler complains about `AClass` being of the wrong type:

```
interface ATypeStatic {
    new(param: number): AType;
}

interface AType {
    field: number;
}

declare var AClass: ATypeStatic;
```

looks like I did not fully grasp the correct useage of 'new' in type declararations.

---

Summary:

I have:

```
 var AClass = function (param) {
    this.field = param;
};
```

I want:

A valid Typescript interface that grasps the ability of this function, to create an object with a paramater called 'field' when called with `new` (which is obviously not the return type of this function).

I don't want:

Anything containig the keyword `class` - I am working with legacy code here that I ought not to change.

I would accept:

Any documentation hint that explains IF and WHY this is not covered by Typescript.

Comment: It looks like the usage of 'new' is limited to classes. But what would the correct type definition for the code above  (a construstor function and its invocation) look like?

Answer (score 0):

Your example works, except you don't end up with an `AClass`, you end up with an `AType`. You can combine the `new` and the field into a single interface:

```
interface AClass {
    new(param: number): AClass;
    field: number;
}

declare var AClass: AClass;

var aVariable = new AClass(1);
```

In this example we preserve the name `AClass` thoughout, and TypeScript knows that you mean the type when you are inside of a type annotation (so it understands the two concepts of `AClass`.

## Alternatively

If you want to place the implementation in the same file... you can dispense with all of this and just have a class:

```
class AClass {
    constructor(public field: number) {
    }
}

var aVariable = new AClass(1);
```

Comment: what I don't like is mixing up Typescript typedefinition names with javascript identifiers, but otherwise it's fine. Still, I miss the constructor function in the example.  `var AClass = function (param) {
        this.field = param;
    };` does not work.

Comment: If you want the implementation in the same file, see my second example (just added).

Answer (score 0):

I would say that the most simple way to make your code works in TS is to use "magic" of the **any** type:

```
var AClass = function (param: string) {
    this.field = param;
};
var aVariable = new (AClass as any)(1);
```

You may add some typing (if needed) and cast the function to the any type, to make it possible to cast it to a custom interface (**IAClassConstructor**):

```
interface IAClass {
    field: any;
}

interface IAClassConstructor {
    new(param: any): IAClass;
}

var AClass: IAClassConstructor = (function (param: string) {
    this.field = param;
} as any);

var aVariable: IAClass = new AClass(1);
```

Here is an [example on the Playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=interface%20IAClass%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20field%3A%20any%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20IAClassConstructor%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20new(param%3A%20any)%3A%20IAClass%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Avar%20AClass%3A%20IAClassConstructor%20%3D%20(function%20(param%3A%20string)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20this.field%20%3D%20param%3B%0D%0A%7D%20as%20any)%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Avar%20aVariable%3A%20IAClass%20%3D%20new%20AClass(1)%3B).

A hint to the answer "Why it's not converted automatically by TS" would be something like: "It's not converted, because functions are not supposed to be used as constructors, and if you want/need to use functions that way, you need to cast them to correct types".